# Enforce HTTPS not available on GitHub

Tags: github, ssl, https, web-deployment, namecheap

I was able to have HTTPS but just recently I cannot create an HTTPS website. Is there anyone familiar with Namecheap and GitHub Pages that has either overcome the issue or can help?

[Namecheap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBDtt.png)

[GitHub Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9acnq.png)

[CNAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyvZQ.png)

[404.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HErU3.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PztyY.png)

Comment: I have the same issue again. I fixed it a couple months ago but I forgot what I did. I'll response ASAP with any information about it.

Comment: @ParkingMaster did you remember? :)

Comment: @VadimKovrizhkin Actually yes! Thanks for asking. I'll put my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @VadimKovrizhkin for asking. Yes, I do remember now.

#### Step 1

(*I did not try this, but it is definetely related to the problem*)

Try disabling all extensions. If the checkbox is enabled, re-enable all extensions one-by-one to see which one it is. If you find which one it is, you may not need to permanently disable it.

The extension may have settings/preferences. For example, mine was an ad-blocker. I went to its preferences in my browser settings. Then, I disabled it on the specific site I wanted.

I have not tried this out on this problem though.

#### Step 2

If that did not work, here's what helped me enable the checkbox.

This step is very simple.

Go to the "Pages" section (or wherever the checkbox is)

[image: checkbox]

Lay your cursor over the checkbox.

Right click, "Inspect Element", and go to the element manually if it doesn't automatically.

[image: checkbox 2]

Find the attribute on the `<input type="checkbox">` element called `disabled`.

Completely delete that attribute from the element.

[image: checkbox 3]

The checkbox should be enabled again.

#### The reason it may not be working

It looks like this issue has not been fixed yet.

I can tell because I ran into this problem a few days ago setting my domain.

I did the inspect element trick and it works great.

The reason it may be doing this is browser support, or an extension(s) that may be breaking the site.

Other GitHub users have had browser support issues on Firefox and Chrome (maybe other browser too).